# How to use import pacakge(Error:test.aux not found)import

Tags: input, include, import

I tries to run my latex as a project, with each section using a different text file. But I seem unable to let import command do what I want it to do.

Here is the MWE:
mainfile

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{import}
\begin{document}
\section{test}
 \import{/section}{testtest}
\end{document}
```

subfile

`testtest`

directory structure:

mainfile[image]

errorquote:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `test.aux' not found.
>
> Type X to quit or  to proceed, or enter new name. (Default
> extension: aux)
>
> Enter file name:

Comment: personally I wouldn't use `import` it complicates the processing for only cosmetic benefit but if you do use it `/section` would refer to a directory at the root of the filesystem which probably is not what you mean here

Comment: You probably want `./section`, if your main file is in the folder above "section" folder, and your `testest`.tex file is in the "section" folder.

Comment: @cicada thank you. You are correct, I need to add the dot before the section. Thank you so much.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what would you do. If it is not too much to ask

Comment: or just `{section}`  I would use the standard latex `\input` not `\import`